# How to run a Python script requiring webcam from a web page

Tags: python, html, opencv

I have written a Python script which uses the OpenCV library and my PC's webcam for facial recognition.

I have made a website to demonstrate this script. So how can I run this script by putting a button on my website which says "Try the script out" (obviusly) and clicking the button runs the script as it does on my PC..??

Comment: Browsers can only execute javascript. So, you either need to write your program in js or run your python script on a web server and connect your client through REST apis (or web sockets maybe).

Comment: @RaviKumar Can't I do this entire thing offline? It is meant for a demonstration only.

Comment: You can run a web server on your local machine ( on 127.0.0.1).

Comment: @RaviKumar That still doesn't answer my question. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you using any web framework for building your website?

Comment: @RaviKumar No I'm building it from scratch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141708/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-and-yaddyvirus).